# Will SSRS handle such a large dataset?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have been asked to create a proof of concept (POC) on a large dataset - 300million records give or take.

I have managed to create this quite well using Qliksense but now am trying to create something usable with SSRS.  In Qliksense I was able to pull in the data unaggregated but I am scared to do this with SSRS as I am confident it will give me an error and timeout.

I'd appreciate suggestions in terms of how to handle this ask.  The data itself is pretty simple:
FINANCIAL data for 2 years with Account_number and Customer_Key.
CUSTOMER dimension data with Account_Number and Customer_Key.

I can join the 2 together using the mentioned fields.  This is all on SQL 2012 and I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to design my report.

Comment: My opinion about SSRS (as well as most of the other add-on products that ship with SQL Server) is that it does enough to get by for most of the people that use SQL Server. However, when you start trying to use it for Enterprise level reporting, that's where it becomes brittle and buckles under pressure (usually when you need it most). But - I have to ask - what is the logic and how useful/human readable is a report that has 300 million records in it?

Comment: What is the actual question here? Why don't you try this in SSRS? Then you will know for sure. Surely you have a dev environment for this type of thing right?

Comment: I'm assuming that your report will not display all 300 million records, if it does then I'm not sure how that can ever be useful but that's your choice. If you mean you want to report on 300 million records by aggregating, or showing a range of accounts etc then the issue will purely be down to your queries extracting the data. If you always try to reduce what you send to SSRS rather than relying on it to do all the leg work then you'll probably be OK. I create reports based on 30 million records quite often with no issues.

Comment: I think Alan Schofield's comment is most important. How are you using the data?  SSRS helps mostly with presentation to people.  Is the result for people to look at?  What will you actually show -- 300 million rows, or some calculated result?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  What I have in mind is to present the data using a matrix so it will be aggregated.  However, I was worried about sending 300m records to SSRS and expecting it to crunch the numbers for the matrix and I think that I'll need to pre-aggregate the numbers for the purposes of reporting.  Then I can do some kind of drill through for details if these are required.